# How can I run automated GUI tests for JVM apps without interrupting my work?

Tags: automation

I need to write automated GUI tests for apps built with and running on OpenJDK 14 (Swing & JFX) on Catalina.

This is easy, but when the tests are running the windows pop up on my screen, taking focus and interrupting my work.

On Linux I use xvfb to create a new virtual display (say 99) and run my tests with the environment variable `DISPLAY=:99` and all is good.

However, OpenJDK on OS/X no longer has X11 bindings, so it is not possible to target an X11 environment.

Is there a way to do the equivalent on OS/X? I was wondering about scripting the creation of a new Desktop, without making it the currently displayed one, and ensuring that it is used as the Desktop on which to launch the app, but I haven't worked out how.

Prior research:
No answer to [Is there a Mac-native equivalent of xvfb for running on a headless Mac server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331998/is-there-a-mac-native-equivalent-of-xvfb-for-running-on-a-headless-mac-server)

Comment: Would a virtual machine or a docker container running Linux be an option?  VirtualBox is free so a good place to start.

Comment: I run the full build in a docker container, so it's not a problem there, I just use xvfb. But it's substantially slower than running locally, so I like to do a quick `gw check` so that I get quicker feedback if I've broken a unit test or upset my linter.

I can probably work around it by skipping the gui tests locally, but it would be nice if they ran.

Comment: If it is much slower it may have too little memory

Comment: Docker has access to 6g, and I've given gradle 2g. It's 19 seconds locally, 45 as a docker build; for me that's a big difference.

(It's actually a bit more as I separate downloading dependencies in the dockerfile from doing the build, so that the build can be done offline, which adds another 14 seconds.)

Comment: Actually more like 11 seconds locally using the gradle daemon.

Comment: Do you run on the volume mounted from the host?  That is slow.

Comment: I run it in the Dockerfile, as part of a multistage build. I'm using the experimental buildkit features to cache the `~/.gradle` directory, otherwise it would have to redownload gradle & all the dependencies, which takes minutes.

Comment: It's not an answer, but I've given up & just disabled the tests unless the JVM reports the graphics device is X11 and the display is `:99`, or they are not running as part of the gradle build.

This means they run as part of the docker build, and they run if I run the test directly in the IDE, but are skipped when I do a local build, so no unexpected windows popping up and grabbing focus.

Comment: What about installing [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) for an X11 environment so you can test in the manner you're used to. Disclaimer  I haven't tested XQuartz on Catalina yet so YMMV.

Comment: Modern JVMs don't use X11 on Mac